# AIDE error: Method onRewardedVideoCompleted does not override method from superclass

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide, aide

I am getting this AIDE (Android IDE) error: "Method onRewardedVideoCompleted does not override method from superclass". The weird part is there is no errors in Android Studio. I followed this guide: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video

I am getting this error in AIDE:

[image]

Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/TJCPw5BH

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.

This is what I did to resolve it:

In RNFirebaseAdMobRewardedVideo.java:

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
  // Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", 
  // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  sendEvent("onRewardedVideoCompleted", null);
}
```

And if you receive this error after adding that code: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease', add this to your app build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Please let me know if this works!